# What does In [*] at the upper left-hand of the cell mean when running a jupyter notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

What does `In [*]` at the upper left-hand of the cell mean when running a jupyter notebook and how I can resolve this?

Please any one can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the cell is running, or in queue to be run. You don't *solve* it really, you just have to wait for the cell to finish executing. If you think the cell has gotten stuck for some reason, you can try to interrupt it by going to "Kernel" in the menu bar and selecting "Interrupt". When the cell is finished running, a number will appear instead of a star. The number is the order in which that cell was executed in this session.

If you have a cell that takes a really long time to execute, I suggest outputting some periodic status to the user. I like to do something like:

```py
update_freq = 100  # or however often you want it to update you
print('Running', end='', flush=True)
for iter in range(a_whole_lot_of_iterations):
    # ... code that runs for a long time or for a ton of iterations ...
    if iter >= update_freq and iter % summary_freq == 0:
        print('.', end='', flush=True)  # periodically print something
print('done!')
```

You can get as fancy as you want with this approach, printing all kinds of cool stuff in your first line as a header, controlling how many updates are printed total to the screen so you can create a sort of ASCII status bar, etc. I found [this guide to the Python string formatting language](https://pyformat.info/) helpful when figuring out how to make nicely formatted status updates.